# Double Linked List Insertion in Between

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to write the code for the following question:

> Insert an element(sum of neighbors) between every pair of consecutive elements?
>
> Example: if input is
>
> ```
> 12 23 34 45 for n=4
> ```
>
> Output should be:
>
> ```
> 12 35 23 57 34 79 45
> ```

The code I wrote is:

```
struct node *InsBet(node *head) {
    node *i,*j,*t;
    i=head;
    while(i->next!=NULL) {
        t = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        t->data = i->data + i->next->data;
        i->next = t;t->prev = i;
        t->next = i->next;i->next->prev = t;
        i = i->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Upon printing the array it is crashing my terminal.

My print program is:

```
void PrintList(node *head) {
    node *i;
    i=head;
    while(i!=NULL) {
        printf("%d ",i->data);
        i=i->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first problem** is that you're overriding `i->next` before copying it to `t->next`

Switch the order of

```
    i->next = t;t->prev = i;
    t->next = i->next;i->next->prev = t;
```

into

```
    t->next = i->next; i->next->prev = t; 
    i->next = t; t->prev = i;
```

To elaborate, assume you have a chain of 2 elements in your list: `A-->B`, and you want to add the temporary element between, so you create `t`, but since the first thing you do is overwrite the forward pointer of the first element (`A` in this case), you lose any chance of ever accessing `B` again. Instead, you assign into the forward pointer of the temporary element the address of itselfm creating an infinite loop.

**The second problem** is that you advance the current pointer (`i`) by only one link, which means it would now point to the temporary element you've just added, and you would try to add an additional temporary element between `t` and `B`. This would cause an infinite loop - instead advance i by -

```
i = t->next;
```

Comment: Sorry Can u say what does to the program please and can U give the update code.

Comment: Still my terminal is cashing after that can u find the mistake

Comment: @RamanaUday You're right, there was a second bug - see my last edit

Comment: Sorry again @Leeror but I am getting a segmentation fault fault now while printing

Comment: @RamanaUday, you'll need to debug which node causes the crash, and then track to see how it was introduced. It could be a problem in the function calling the print (you didn't provide that code)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer explained it very well but just to give you a working code, here you go:

PS, you don't need to return the head pointer because its passed by reference and there is no use in returning it

```
void InsBet(node *head) {
    node *i,*t;
    i=head;
    while(i->next!=NULL) {
        t = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        t->data = i->data + i->next->data;
        t->prev = i;
        t->next = i->next;
        i->next = i->next->next;
        i->prev = t;

        i = t->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: But during printing in main I will be using head = CreateLinkedList(int n); and InsBet(head); so after that i will be printing PrintList(head); so which head it will be using during PrintList. And thank for the code.

Comment: There will only be one head for one linkedList. if you compare it with an array, the head is the first element